# I am trying to figure out how to sort this Dataset. SAS Beginner

Tags: sas

How do i start this??
I have two data sets.

For the output you will deliver:
It should be an excel or XML format
Each query logic/programmed check should be on each tab
Columns should be

```
Subject #,
Visit Date (You will need the Visit Date Listing also attached)
Visit Name (Visit date from the file_34422 must match Visit name in the Blood Pressure File)
Date of Assessment (From the BP Log), VSBPDT_RAW, VSTPT, BP results.
A column for SYBP1. SYBP2, SYBP3, DIABP1, DIABP2, DIABP3
Findings/query text.
```

Below are Specification for BP:

**For same SUBJECT and same FOLDERNAME, where VSTPT is Blood Pressure 1.**

- if  VSBPYN is No, then all must be null or =0 (VSBPDT_RAW, VSBPTM1, SYSBP1, DIABP1, VSBPND2, VSBPTM2, SYSBP2, DIABP2, VSBPND3, VSBPTM3, SYSBP3, DIABP3)

This is what i have started with and

proc sql;

```
    select

       f.subject, 
       f.SVSTDT_RAW, f.FolderName,
       b.FolderName, 
       VSBPDT_RAW, VSTPT, 
       SYSBP1, SYSBP2, SYSBP3, 
        DIABP1, DIABP2, DIABP3

FROM first_data as f, bp_data as b
group by subject, foldername
where f.subject = b.subject 
having VSTPT is Blood Pressure set 1,
       VSBPYN is No;
```

quit;

I just need to be pointed towards the right direction. I know this can't be right.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A reminder that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. To get a response and ensure that your question does not get closed, please show us what you have tried and and post some sample data as a downloadable .sas7bdat file, csv file, or in `datalines` format.

Comment: Please review the guidelines here on how to ask a question [ask]. Usually, starting off, with this is what I have, this is what I want and this is what I've tried so far is a good idea.

Comment: @StuSztukowski any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact structure of your data, so the solution below may need to be modified by you to select the right columns.

From the descritpion, this looks like it might be a good situation for SQL and a data step. You have a lot of columns to merge with the `bp` table. It will be easy to do merge all of these columns with `first_data` in SQL.

When you have lots of by-row conditionals, a data step will be easier to work with and read than many `CASE` statements in SQL. We'll do a two-stage approach in which we use SQL and a data step.

**Step 1: Merge the data**

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table stage as
        select t1.*
             , t2.VSBPYN
        from bp_data    as t1
        INNER JOIN
             first_data as t2
        ON t1.subject     = t2.subject
           AND foldername = t2.foldername
        where t1.VSTPT = 1
    ;
quit;
```

**Step 2: Conditionally set values to missing**

Next, we'll do a data step for our conditional logic. `call missing()` is a useful function that will let you set the value of many variables to missing all in a single statement.

```
data want;
    set stage;
    
    if(upcase(VSBPYN) = 'NO') then call missing(VSBPDT_RAW, VSBPTM1, SYSBP1, DIABP1,
                                                VSBPND2, VSBPTM2, SYSBP2, DIABP2, 
                                                VSBPND3, VSBPTM3, SYSBP3, DIABP3
                                               );
run;
```

**Step 3: Output to Excel**

Finally, we sent the output to Excel.

```
proc export 
    data=want
    file='/my/location/want.xlsx' 
    dbms=xlsx
    replace;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll get started with this and share my results..

Comment: for the VSTPT = Blood Pressure Set 1. why did you use 1? 
After running the first code, i got an error message     


ERROR: Expression using equals (=) has components that are of different data types.

Comment: In your question, it states: "where VSTPT is Blood Pressure 1." This would directly translate to a `where` statement.  If it is giving errors about different data types, then VSTPT is a character variable and you will need to either convert it to numeric or specify `VSTPT= '1'`.  Maybe it means where VSTPT literally equals "Blood Pressure 1." You did not post downloadable sample data or a data structure, so I do not know what your data contains. I cannot help you much further from here.

Comment: How do i share sample data??

Comment: Yes VSTPT = "Blood Pressure Set 1"... With this i would be able to do the others..

Comment: Thanks for your assistance..
How do i input the difference in the data step
For same SUBJECT and same FOLDERNAME, where VSTPT is Blood Pressure 1.
VSBPYN = Yes
For Same VSBPDT_RAW,
Check for difference of 8 between SYSBP1, SYSBP2, SYSBP3..